# Autowiring Embedded Elastic with Spring

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, autowired

I'm trying to build a rest api with Spring and Embedded Elastic. I'm getting an NoSuchBeanDefinitionException when trying to start my application.

Currently, I have this for wiring the elastic db:

```
@Configuration
public class EsConfig {
    Node node;

    @Bean
    public Client es() {
        node = nodeBuilder().local(true).node();
        return node.client();
    }

    (Destructor)
}
```

and in the controller:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    public Client elasticSearchClient;
...
}
```

But when I start it up, I get this exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'controller': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public org.elasticsearch.client.Client package.Controller.elasticSearchClient;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
    No qualifying bean of type [org.elasticsearch.client.Client] found for dependency:
    expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I've tried a few different annotations but I'm obviously way off.

Comment: Which bean is it missing? Can you include the exception in your question? Not sure what an empty `@Qualifier` does but you don't need it if you don't specify a qualifier.

Comment: It's missing the Client bean in the Controller class. I updated the question to include the meat of the exception.  I had a name in the qualifier before and just forgot to remove it completely.  Like I said, I've been trying a lot of different things.

Comment: ah, try making your config an `@Configuration`, that is a class that provides `@Bean`s, a `@Component` is merely a `@Bean` itself. And get rid of the qualifier if you don't use the named bean approach :)

Comment: Okay, changed to @Configuration and dropped the Qualifier but I'm still seeing the same exception.

Comment: The bean is a `org.elasticsearch.client.Client` and the configuration class is within the scanned packages? "No bean of type Client" basically  means that spring doesn't use/see your @Bean method. If you put a no-argument method annotatated(is that a word?) with `@PostConstruct` and some println / log in it in the config class, do you see it? Or simply put log into the bean method and see if it's called.

Comment: You're my hero!  Nothing was showing up when I added some prints to the method so I moved it inside the package that contains the @SpringBootApplication and now I have a new error!  It's just port already in use so it should be easy to fix.  Thank you!  If you want to summarize your suggestions, I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`No qualifying bean of type [some.Thing]` means that spring knowns no class that is applicable for this interface.

Reasons for that can be

- The class that has the `@Bean` method is not a `@Configuration` class
- The `@Configuration` class is not picked up by the classpath component scanner.

Spring boot by default will only scan the child package hierarchy of the `@SpringBootApplication`. If you  want to include code outside of that you can change the scanning behavior via the `@ComponentScan` annotation.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {MyApp.class, SomeOtherClassInARootPackage.class})
public class MyApp {
...
```

Would add the package (and sub packages) of some other class, while keeping the packages of the application scanned as well.